# Unexplainable side effects of a function on other unrelated ones in C

Tags: c, linux, function, pointers, gcc

The following program is supposed to copy the source array's elements into the target arrays using different pointer reference notations in each function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void copy_arr(double [], const double [], int);
void copy_ptr(double *, const double *, int);
void copy_ptrs(double *, const double *, double *);
void print_arr(const double *, const double *);

int main(void)
{
  double source[5] = { 0.1, 2.2, 4.3, 6.4, 8.5};
  double target1[5];
  double target2[5];
  double target3[5];

  copy_arr(target1, source, 5);
  copy_ptr(target2, source, 5);

  copy_ptrs(target3, source, source + 5);

  print_arr(target1, target1 + 5);
  print_arr(target2, target2 + 5);
  print_arr(target3, target3 + 5);

  return 0;
}

void copy_arr(double target[], const double source[], int num)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    target[i] = source[i];
}

void copy_ptr(double *target, const double *source, int num)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    *(target+i) = *(source+i);
}

void copy_ptrs(double *target, const double *source, double *end)
{
  for (; target < end; ++target, ++source)
    *target = *source;
}

void print_arr(const double *start, const  double *end)
{
  while ( start < end)
    printf("%.1lf, ", *start++);
  printf("\n");
}
```

This produces outputs like:

```
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.1, 2.2, 4.3, 6.4, 8.5,
```

or garbage in the place of the zeroes.

However when I accidentally changed the copy_ptrs function to:

```
void copy_ptrs(double *target, const double *source, double *end)
    {
      for (; *target < *end; ++target, ++source) // notice the asterisks
        *target = *source;
    }
```

I get the following output:

```
0.1 2.2 4.3 6.4 8.5 
0.1 2.2 4.3 6.4 8.5 
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Apparently the "mistake" causes the `copy_arr` and `copy_ptr` to function properly, but when I remove the asterisks from the variable names in the for loop of `copy_ptrs`, it **causes** the two previous functions to malfunction, while it itself works.

To re-iterate: dereferencing the `target` and `end` variables produces the right output for the third function, but 'breaks' the two previous ones; and not doing so breaks its respective function. I think not dereferencing the pointers `start` and `end` is the right way to go, because the `print_arr` does not dereference them, but behaves as expected (and according to my understanding, is the proper way).

How can this change affect code that supposedly runs **before** it's supposed to be reach. And overall, what's wrong with the program?

I'm using GCC 4.8.5 on Linux.

Comment: You're reading uninitialized data from the `*target`; all bets are off as to what you get.

Comment: by the time the targets are read by `print_arr` they were copied to by the `copy_` functions.

Comment: The problem is in the second `copy_ptrs()` and the use of `*target < *end`.  You're reading `*target` before it is assigned a value, and in fact `*end` doesn't have a determinate value either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest problem with `copy_ptrs()` is the end condition:

```
void copy_ptrs(double *target, const double *source, double *end)
{
  for (; target < end; ++target, ++source)
    *target = *source;
}
```

Note that this is invoked with:

```
copy_ptrs(target3, source, source + 5);
```

You should be checking that `source` is less than `end`:

```
void copy_ptrs(double *target, const double *source, double *end)
{
  for (; source < end; ++target, ++source)
    *target = *source;
}
```

So, you're copying indeterminate amounts of data around the place in the original, trampling outside the bounds of the arrays.  A lot depends on how the arrays are laid out by the compiler.  It looks like you're (un)fortunate that `target3` is laid out at an address lower than `source`, so incrementing `target` often enough gets to `end` before you overwrite something critical and crash.

Comment: Also, do you know how my mistake was able to affect the previous functions even though it was supposed to be executed afterwards?

Comment: Because all sorts of data was being copied from goodness knows where over the other target arrays.  The chances are you were copying 10 double's worth of data after the `source` over `target1` and `target2` before modifying `source` and then stopping.

Comment: If you want to experiment, increase the size of `source` to at least 20 elements (add something distinctive for the values) — without changing the invocations of the copy functions.  Then, with the incorrect `copy_ptrs()`, watch for those distinctive values in the results.  You could print `source` too.  You could print `target1` immediately after it is set, and again after `target2` is set (and print `target2` of course), and then print them all again after the faulty (and fixed!) `copy_ptrs()` invocation.

Comment: That demonstrated the issue. Thanks a lot! :)